# Method always wants me to keep other ones in static

Tags: java, static

I'm currently writing an password solver in java.

I know what static means, but sometimes I'm not able to find the most simple solutions.

I don't want any static variables.

I'm think it is because of the main method in my first class, but I am nit sure.

```
package Main;

public class Main {

    Main() {
        new CodeSolver();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

CodeSolver:

```
package Main;

import GUI.Frame;

public class CodeSolver {
    String codeOld;
    String code ;

    String[] ID;

    public CodeSolver(){
        RegisterId();
        new Frame(code);
    }

    public String giveCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public void RegisterId(){
        ID = new String[62];

        ID[0] = "a"; ID[1] = "b"; ID[2] = "c"; ID[3] = "d"; ID[4] = "e"; ID[5] = "f"; ID[6] = "g"; ID[7] = "h"; ID[8] = "i"; ID[9] = "j"; ID[10] = "k"; ID[11] = "l"; ID[12] = "m"; ID[13] = "n"; ID[14] = "o"; ID[15] = "p";
        ID[16] = "q"; ID[17] = "r"; ID[18] = "s"; ID[19] = "t"; ID[20] = "u"; ID[21] = "v"; ID[22] = "w"; ID[23] = "x"; ID[24] = "y"; ID[25] = "z"; 
        ID[26] = "A"; ID[27] = "B"; ID[28] = "C"; ID[29] = "D"; ID[30] = "E"; ID[31] = "F"; ID[32] = "G"; ID[33] = "H"; ID[34] = "I"; ID[35] = "J"; ID[36] = "K"; ID[37] = "L"; ID[38] = "M"; ID[39] = "N"; ID[40] = "O"; ID[41] = "P"; 
        ID[42] = "Q"; ID[43] = "R"; ID[44] = "S"; ID[45] = "T"; ID[46] = "U"; ID[47] = "V"; ID[48] = "W"; ID[49] = "X"; ID[50] = "Y"; ID[51] = "Z"; 
        ID[52] = "0"; ID[53] = "1"; ID[54] = "2"; ID[55] = "3"; ID[56] = "4"; ID[57] = "5"; ID[58] = "6"; ID[59] = "7"; ID[60] = "8"; ID[61] = "9";
    }

    public void TestLabel(){
        for(int i=0; i <= ID.length; i++){
            codeOld = code;
            code = ID[i];
            System.out.println(ID[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Frame:

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Main.CodeSolver;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String code01;
    String code;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;

    public Frame(String codeNew){
        code = codeNew;

        this.setTitle("CodeSolver");
        this.setSize(600, 300);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 300);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        label = new JLabel(code);
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 300);
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

        label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica New", Font.PLAIN, 60));
        label.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(label);

        this.add(panel);
    }

    public void getCode(){
        code01 = CodeSolver.giveCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a little confusing, what method? I dont see any static method besides the main method here.

Comment: I think the only static variable is serialVersionUID

Comment: Instead of `new Main()` in the `static main` method, you could do `new CodeSolver()` because that is all you are doing anyway

Comment: I think it is his last line of code where he calls `code01 = CodeSolver.giveCode()` but `giveCode()` isn't static.  The java compiler should give an error in that context.

Comment: You also may need to consider giving your `code` variable in your `CodeSolver` some consideration here. It looks like once `giveCode()` is called, `code` will be null.

Comment: @callyalater i think he should tell us explicitly, we are literally guessing.

Comment: Calling `TestLabel()` will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException :D

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly the compiler is saying?

Answer (score 3):

You can't access a non-static method in a static context:

```
public void getCode(){
    code01 = CodeSolver.giveCode(); //This is not a static method
}
```

Either make the `giveCode()` method static (and all that entails) or create an instance member and call `giveCode()` on that instance.

Comment: As I do not know if the method was intended to be static and therefore require a static variable or if he intends to have an instance member variable of type CodeSolver and call the method on that instance, I can't properly give a suggested fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need an **instance** of the CodeSolver because the `getCode()` method is not static, meaning you can't use the class to access that method.

You should also separate the concerns of the Frame from the CodeSolver, they are **seperate** objects entirely. A Frame should **use** the CodeSolver, the CodeSolver should not **manage** or **depend on** the Frame.

So, the recommended approach is remove it from the CodeSolver, and create an instance of the CodeSolver in the Frame.

For example, (this displays a black box? not sure where that green label is supposed to be...)

**CodeSolver** - Add a `solve()` method that operates on the `codeToSolve` field and returns the solved code.

```
public class CodeSolver {
    String[] ID;
    String codeToSolve;

    public CodeSolver(){
        this("");
    }

    public CodeSolver(String codeToSolve) {
        registerId();
        this.codeToSolve = codeToSolve;
    }

    public String solve(){

        String code = "";
        // Do some work on this.codeToSolve

        return code;
    }

    public void registerId(){
        ID = new String[62];

        ID[0] = "a"; ID[1] = "b"; ID[2] = "c"; ID[3] = "d"; ID[4] = "e"; ID[5] = "f"; ID[6] = "g"; ID[7] = "h"; ID[8] = "i"; ID[9] = "j"; ID[10] = "k"; ID[11] = "l"; ID[12] = "m"; ID[13] = "n"; ID[14] = "o"; ID[15] = "p";
        ID[16] = "q"; ID[17] = "r"; ID[18] = "s"; ID[19] = "t"; ID[20] = "u"; ID[21] = "v"; ID[22] = "w"; ID[23] = "x"; ID[24] = "y"; ID[25] = "z";
        ID[26] = "A"; ID[27] = "B"; ID[28] = "C"; ID[29] = "D"; ID[30] = "E"; ID[31] = "F"; ID[32] = "G"; ID[33] = "H"; ID[34] = "I"; ID[35] = "J"; ID[36] = "K"; ID[37] = "L"; ID[38] = "M"; ID[39] = "N"; ID[40] = "O"; ID[41] = "P";
        ID[42] = "Q"; ID[43] = "R"; ID[44] = "S"; ID[45] = "T"; ID[46] = "U"; ID[47] = "V"; ID[48] = "W"; ID[49] = "X"; ID[50] = "Y"; ID[51] = "Z";
        ID[52] = "0"; ID[53] = "1"; ID[54] = "2"; ID[55] = "3"; ID[56] = "4"; ID[57] = "5"; ID[58] = "6"; ID[59] = "7"; ID[60] = "8"; ID[61] = "9";
    }

    public void testLabel(){
        for (int i = 0; i < ID.length; i++){
            System.out.println(ID[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Frame** - Store an instance of the CodeSolver and make the `getCode()` method call `solve()` from above.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    String code;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;

    CodeSolver solver;

    public Frame(String codeToSolve){
        initGUI();
        this.solver = new CodeSolver(codeToSolve);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        this.setTitle("CodeSolver");
        this.setSize(600, 300);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 300);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        label = new JLabel(code);
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 300);
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica New", Font.PLAIN, 60));

        panel.add(label);
        this.add(panel);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return this.solver.solve();
    }
}
```

**Main**

Here is where you can pass in the string that you want to solve. Also, run the GUI on a proper Thread.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runCodeSolver("cricket_007");
    }

    public static void runCodeSolver(final String code) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Frame frame = new Frame(code);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```